# pandas dataframe check specific columns for same values

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to check and sum specific dataframe columns for the same values.

For example in the following dataframe

```
column name 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
            -------------
            a, g, h, t, j 
            b, a, o, a, g
            c, j, w, e, q
            d, b, d, q, i
```

when comparing columns 1 and 2 the sum of values that are the same is 2 (a and b)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isin` and `sum` to achieve this:

```
In [96]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""1, 2, 3, 4, 5
a, g, h, t, j 
b, a, o, a, g
c, j, w, e, q
d, b, d, q, i"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=',\s+')
df

Out[96]:
   1  2  3  4  5
0  a  g  h  t  j
1  b  a  o  a  g
2  c  j  w  e  q
3  d  b  d  q  i

In [100]:    
df['1'].isin(df['2']).sum()

Out[100]:
2
```

`isin` will produce a boolean series, calling sum on a boolean series converts `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` respectively:

```
In [101]:
df['1'].isin(df['2'])

Out[101]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

**EDIT**

To check and count the number of values that are present in all columns of interest the following would work, note that for your dataset there are no values that are present in all columns:

```
In [123]:
df.ix[:, :'4'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(df['1'])).all(axis=1).sum()

Out[123]:
0
```

Breaking the above down will show what each step is doing:

```
In [124]:    
df.ix[:, :'4'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(df['1']))

Out[124]:
      1      2      3      4
0  True  False  False  False
1  True   True  False   True
2  True  False  False  False
3  True   True   True  False

In [125]:    
df.ix[:, :'4'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(df['1'])).all(axis=1)

Out[125]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks great it works!.  Is it possible to compare 4 columns for the same values as well?

Comment: Sorry you mean compare column '1' with all ther other columns?

Comment: sorry, no I mean compare say columns 1,2,3,4 and return the sum of all values that appear in all 4 columns (thanks)

Comment: Well for your sample dataset you have no values that are in all the first 4 columns, are you looking just for values that are in all 4 columns?

Comment: Thanks, Ed the dataset will update and there will be a high probability that there will be values in all 4 columns that would be the same.  So yes I am looking for values that would be present in all 4 of the columns

Comment: Hi Many thanks for all the answers, I have tried to apply the                  df.ix[:, :'4'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(df['1'])).all(axis=1).sum()                            to the last 4 columns of my example (columns 2,3,4 and 5)  by using df.ix[:, :'5'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(df['2'])).all(axis=1).sum()   and have checked by hand (with a dataset that provides me an answer greater than 0, but keep getting a different result.  Have I applied the logic correctly please?